# How to stop tinymce converting html tags from database

Tags: html

I can create my content fine using tinymce , it also uploads correctly to the database. here is an example of  what stores in the database.

```
<p>Content goes in here</p>
```

When I choose to edit this it converts my p tags in the database to `&lt;p&gt;`
and then wraps the content in another set of p tags.

in source code of tinymce it looks like this

```
<p>&lt;p&gt;this is a test message&lt;/p&gt;</p>
```

How do I stop this ?

as I just want it to render exactly as it is in the database.

I want to still store correct html tags in my database but I do not want tinymce to keep stripping/converting them.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [somethink like that](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding)

```
tinymce.init({
        ...
        entity_encoding : "raw"
});
```

Comment: Hi I have tried adding this and it still displays the same is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

tinymce encode the content before passing it to the server and hence the content is stored as: `&lt;p&gt;This is text;/p&gt;` but the html tage are still passed like `<p>&lt;p&gt;This is text;/p&gt;</p>`

While saving it to the database encode the values so that the html/xml tags are stored encoded. Like; `Server.HtmlEncode(_propertyShopAdvertDetails.MarketingInformation);`
and similarly while retrieving and displaying in the tinymce control the vaue needs to be decoded; 
`Server.HtmlDecode(_propertyShopAdvertDetails.MarketingInformation);`

while retrieving the content and displaying it in the control, it decodes it and displays it correctly. Since it is displaying the content fine so I believe you have the right class on the control and used the correct mode for the plugin.

Now if you want to display the content in an HTML page and not inside tinymce control the you need to decode it. Something like: `@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.PropertyFullDescription))`